# Organize MySQL Customer / Data Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with customer numbers, customer names, and item numbers.  It's a little more complex than this, but I tried to simplify it a little and remove sensitive data.

CURRENT TABLE

```
Unique Customer Number | Customer Name | Item Number
10001                  | Bob           | 20001
10001                  | Bob           | 20002
10001                  | Bob           | 20003
10002                  | Tim           | 20002
10003                  | Frank         | 20001
10003                  | Frank         | 20003
```

I want to break this into a couple of tables so that it's easier to work with.  I was thinking of something similar to this:

CUSTOMER TABLE

```
Unique Customer Number | Customer Name
10001                  | Bob
10002                  | Tim
10003                  | Frank
```

ITEM TABLE

```
Unique Customer Number | 20001 | 20002 | 20003
10001                  | YES   | YES   | YES
10002                  | NO    | YES   | NO
10003                  | YES   | NO    | YES
```

Is there a better way to organize this?
How would I write the PHP code to separate my CURRENT TABLE into my new CUSTOMER / ITEM TABLEs?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a junction table to resolve the many-to-many relationship between customers and items. Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eww ... items as columns ... very bad idea ... you could potentially end up with 50+ columns for basically nothing ...

```
Customers ( CustomerNumber, CustomerName, ... )
Items ( ItemNumber, ItemDescription, ... )
CustomerItemMapping ( CustomerNumber, ItemNumber )
```

Where the CustomerItemMapping both fields are a Foreign Key to the corresponding table values (i.e. CustomerNumber maps to the Customers.CustomerNumber field).